# Google Reflections on Android not getting any classes

Tags: java, android, reflection, reflections

I'm trying to use **Reflections library** to get all classes annotated with a specific Java **annotation**.

I included Reflections library in .gradle file:

```
compile 'org.reflections:reflections:0.9.10'
```

However, the library does not work for me on Android. I'm not getting any hits from neither `getSubTypesOf` nor `getTypesAnnotatedWith`.

Is there anything wrong with my implementation?

```
package sample.anotherapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import org.reflections.Reflections;
import org.reflections.scanners.SubTypesScanner;
import org.reflections.scanners.TypeAnnotationsScanner;

import java.util.Set;

@Deprecated
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Reflections reflections = new Reflections("sample.anotherapp", new SubTypesScanner(false), new TypeAnnotationsScanner());

        Set<Class<? extends AppCompatActivity>> subTypesOf = reflections. getSubTypesOf(AppCompatActivity.class);
        int size = subTypesOf.size();

        Set<Class<?>> annotated = reflections. getTypesAnnotatedWith(Deprecated.class);
        size = annotated.size();
    }
}
```

So the question would probably be... whether Google-reflections library works on Dalvik

Comment: Did you achieve to make it work ?